# TCP Server and Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, server, tcp

After few days of intense search I am still not able to find what is going wrong with the connection between Tkinter and my Server.

My code runs succesfully but it doesn't launch the app, it does nothing, but when I run my other app client.py, I obtain "Connected with the address :  PY_VAR0" And then the app launch but doesn't answer, like it crashed, I also saw that the app doesn't contain the buttons and the text.

Here's the code :

```py
import sys
import socket    
import threading
from tkinter import *


window = Tk()
window.title('Server TCP - Jay')

window.resizable(False,False)
window.geometry("400x250")


#Functions

class Server:

    def __init__(self, ADRESSE, PORT):
        self.ADRESSE = ADRESSE
        self.PORT = PORT      


    def open_connexion(self):
        self.server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.server.bind((self.ADRESSE, self.PORT))
        self.server.listen()
        self.connexion, self.adresse = self.server.accept()
        print("Connecté avec l'adresse : ", adresse)
        while 1:
            window.update()
            data=self.connexion.recv(1024)
            if not data:
                break
        self.connexion.sendall(data)

    def close_connexion(self):
        self.connexion.close()
        self.server.close()


server = Server(b'127.0.0.1', 2009)

#Labels
l1=Label(window, text="Adresse IP :")
l1.place(x=5, y=10)

l2=Label(window, text="Port :")
l2.place(x=5, y=30)

#Entrys
adresse = StringVar()
adresse.set(b"127.0.0.1")
e1=Entry(window, textvariable=adresse)
e1.place(x=75, y=10)

port = IntVar()
port.set = 2009
e2=Entry(window, textvariable=port)
e2.place(x=75, y=30)

#Buttons

b1=Button(window, text="Open Server", command=server.open_connexion())
b1.place(x= 210,y=18)

b2=Button(window, text="Close Server",command=server.close_connexion())
b2.place(x= 300,y=18)

#Text

t1=Text(window, height=10)
t1.place(x=0, y=70)
t1.insert(INSERT, "Server Informations: \n", "tag") 

window.mainloop()
#ADRESSE = '127.0.0.1'
#PORT = 2009
```

So someone have an idea on what should I correct please? I event tried Threading but didn't worked too. Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: `command=server.open_connexion()` and `command=server.close_connexion()` need to be `command=server.open_connexion` and `command=server.close_connexion`. You're calling `close_connexion` ("connection") right away, not when the button is pressed.

Comment: thanks a lot friend! Now the app freeze only after the connexion have been done with the client, should I add threading here?

Comment: `print("Connecté avec l'adresse : ", adresse)` should be `print("Connecté avec l'adresse : ", self.adresse)` instead.  Also I think `self.connexion.sendall(data)` should be inside while block.  Better use thread to handle the client connection, otherwise the while loop will block the application.

Comment: Yes, multithreading will work provided that the work being done in `open_connexion` is mostly waiting on I/O (which appears to be the case).

Comment: thank you so much to you guys! I am beginner and was really stuck with these problem since three days, and nobody else could help me out! so thanks a lot!